# How to hide Pin It button from images on my website when Chrome plugin is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi I have chrome Pinterest plugin installed and when it is enabled, I see "Pin It" button (on hover) on all images on my website, How can i stop "Pin It" button to appear on my website, even when a chrome extension is enabled

After googling, I found the following on a blog:

> You can easily disable this as an individual who has installed the
>   extension, but if you don’t want it to conflict with any other social
>   software you may have on your site, all you need to do is add this to
>   ever IMG tag:
>
> `<img src="myimage.jpg" data-pin-no-hover />`

But that's for single image, is there any other way to override the plugin to disable "pin it" button from chrome extension? using JS/jQuery?

Chrome extension js: http://assets.pinterest.com/ext/cr.js

**EDIT**

`<img src="myimage.jpg" data-pin-no-hover />` doesn't seem to work anymore

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Okay I just read the Pinterest documentation, To disable the pinterest on a page or website,
just add a meta tag:

```
<meta name="pinterest" content="nopin" />
```

And pinterest button will stop appearing on the website anymore.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 9):

Edit, sorry should say that my response addresses your edit specifically:

You need to specify the true switch for the attribute if you just want to disable the hover pin it button on one image.

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" data-pin-no-hover="true" />
```

... will do it

Comment: `data-pin-no-hover="true"` doesn't work anymore, use `nopin="nopin"` https://help.pinterest.com/en/articles/prevent-saves-pinterest-your-site

Comment: @SaurabhSharma actually it still works; in fact it worked over ``nopin= "nopin"`` for me ..

Answer (score 6):

If you want to disable the hover pin it button on Google Chrome, use this mark up in your HEAD:

```
<meta name="pinterest" content="nohover"></meta>
```

You can read more about it on Pinterest's blog: http://businessblog.pinterest.com/post/77184942682/a-smarter-pin-it-button

using the `no pin` code disables pinning on that image

Hope that helps,

Kristie

Comment: Thanks, That's a nice solution too :)

Answer (score 3):

I spent hours to figure this out, only to find that it is as easy as adding this to your image tag

**nopin="nopin"**

Comment: @j morley this helped me

Answer (score 2):

You have **two methods**:

1) Disabling it to a **single image** ([Charlie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22363187/842768)), as you'd have done, but you have forgotten the value `"true"`, it is necessary:

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" data-pin-no-hover="true" />
```

2) Disabling it to the **whole document** ([Saurabh Sharma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22232611/842768)), at  document's `<head>`:

```
<meta name="pinterest" content="nopin" />
```

You just have to chose which case will suit you better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable it for all images, you could try the following jQuery:

```
$('img').attr('data-pin-no-hover', '');
```

Comment: Please check the edit as `data-pin-no-hover` doesn't seem to work anymore

Comment: Would you be able to provide the url for the website in question so I could see the markup?

Answer (score 0):

Charlie's answer from Mar 12 '14 at 20:34 is now outdated. The most reliable method is to add `nopin="nopin"` as an image attribute:

`<img class="block__el--hide" src="path/imgname_1500x900.png" nopin="nopin">`

~DR